# Synchronous Ajax requests with jQuery doesn't work on Adobe Air

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, air

Incredibly synchronous requests sometimes does not work in certain contexts. Has anyone experienced this and have a solution? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you should provide a bit more details here.. What have you tried ? What are "certain contexts" ? You might also want to post some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

asyncBoolean
Default: true
By default, all requests are sent asynchronously (i.e. this is set to true by default). If you need synchronous requests, set this option to false. Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support synchronous operation. Note that synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request is active. As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks. But: the async is already false, I'm using 1.7, some requests to same domain works.. dataType it's "json".

Comment: I used ajaxSetup to set the "data" before call function that executes the ajax request